# How do I append hex bytes to an existing hex byte literal

Tags: python, serial-port

I need to send a command over serial to a device. The command consists of a header and a footer. The header is predefined and the footer is calculated based on an input from the user. I need to append the footer to the header and send this over serial.

For example, a header could consist of 6 hex bytes:

`header = b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06'`

A footer is calculated from a user input:

`footer_value = user_input * constant`

I then convert this value to hex:

`footer_hex = hex(footer_value)`

This hex string then looks like this"

`0x07080910`

My question is how do I produce the completed header and footer to send over serial. In this example the complete command would be:

`header_footer = b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x10\x09\x08\x07'`

This is what I tried previously without success:

```
def move(self, position):
        micro_steps = round(position * 2184533.33)

        micro_steps_hex = hex(micro_steps)
        print (micro_steps_hex)

        micro_steps_hex_bytes = bytes.fromhex(micro_steps_hex[2:])
        print(micro_steps_hex_bytes)

        print(micro_steps_hex_bytes[0])

        command1 = bytearray(b'\x53\x04\x06\x00\x50\x01\x01\x00')
        command1.append(micro_steps_hex_bytes[2])
        command1.append(micro_steps_hex_bytes[1])
        command1.append(micro_steps_hex_bytes[0])
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried in order to get the final value you are after.

Comment: If `footer_value` is an int, its `to_bytes` method should help.

Comment: Yes, you don't want `hex()`, you want `to_bytes()`, but perhaps with `byteorder='little'`?